# Capture Silverlight 4 event when panel clicked

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, mouseevent

I have a small Silverlight 4 app that essentially consists of a grid containing a label and a combo box.  When I click the label, I replace it with a second text box so that I can edit the label (much the way you can edit the name of a Silverlight control in VS2010).

I have a LostFocus event handler on the text box that will end editing when the control loses focus (restoring the updated label).  Trouble is, users tend to click on the panel when they are done editing rather than on another control (or hitting Enter, which is also supported).

I tried adding a left mouse down event handler to the panel.  However, that only fires when the text box does not have the focus (I guess the text box captured the mouse?)

Is there an approach to recognize that a non-input control was clicked that would enable me to terminate edit mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to Grid's MouseLeftButtonDown routed event using the following code:

```
panel.AddHandler(UIElement.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,
    new MouseButtonEventHandler(panel_OnMouseLeftButtonDown), true);
```

Unlike common events routed events are bubbled from innermost control to its parent, then to grandparent etc. In the same way you could subscribe to panel's parent to intercept clicks outside your panel.